# Where did my Google Chrome incognito mode go?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

When I use the menu, there is no incognito mode option. It's not even grayed out, it doesn't exist.

I checked the registry and there's a value in there that seems to be the culprit:

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome]`
`"IncognitoModeAvailability"=dword:00000001`

If I change the value then restart Chrome, it changes itself back when I reopen Chrome. If I delete it, it recreates itself.

What is causing this?

Comment: Is the account you're logged into in Google Chrome (assuming you're logged into a Google account) an account that you own, or is it part of a Google For Work/Education account?  If it is the latter, your account can have that feature disabled.

Comment: Hmm I created the account using my work email. How would I check what type of account it is?

Comment: If you created the account, then it is not (likely) a managed account.